# Green thread in Ruby 1.9?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

Ruby 1.9 uses native threads unlike Ruby 1.8 (MRI).

But is it possible to kindly ask Ruby 1.9.3 to create a green thread instead of a native one?

--

**Why do I want that?**

For testing purposes.

I'm trying to create a simple TCP server that would accept thousands concurrent connections that would sleep for a couple of seconds before returning some result.

In Ruby 1.8 I can easily create thousands of threads so the only limit for the number of concurrent connections is OS.

In Ruby 1.9 that seems to be impossible.

This code demonstrates what I mean:

```
require 'thread'

m = Mutex.new
c = 0
ta = Array.new 10000

ta.fill do
  Thread.new do
    m.synchronize { c += 1; p "created #{c}th" if c%100 == 0; }
    sleep 15
    m.synchronize { c -= 1; p "destroyed #{c+1}th" if c%100 == 0; }
  end
end

ta.each {|t| t.join}
```

It runs great in Ruby 1.8, but in 1.9 it's so miserable.

--

Unfortunately after some experimenting with eventmachine and its `add_timer` the best I could come up with was Node.js server:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  setTimeout(function() {res.end('Hello World\n');}, 10000 );
}).listen(8081, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/');
```

If anyone could demonstrate the same with EventMachine I would be glad to accept that answer.

Comment: Are fibers out of the question?

Comment: @pje updated the question, you can't replace threads with fibers in that code right?

Comment: Just a note that `setTimeout` is not at all the same as `sleep`. `setTimeout` schedules a function to run sometime in the future. It's an asynchronous, non-blocking method, whereas `sleep` will CPU block the current thread for the specified amount of time.

Comment: @tabdulla yes, that's the reason why I mentioned EventMachine - its `add_timer` supposed to be the same as addTimeout but I failed to make it work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To put it short, the answer is no. The threading model in 1.9 now uses native threads and green threads are deprecated per se.

It would be helpful to hear exactly why you want to use green threads instead of OS-managed ones to suggest proper alternatives. Depending on your use case, you could look into using, for example, **Proc** objects with some kind of roll-your-own scheduling or **Fibers** as lightweight alternatives to native threads. You could also look into Thread / Fiber pooling if you find that the creation time of threads is a limiting factor.

Comment: Thnx for the answer - updated my question. I don't think using Fibers is an option in my case, or is it?

Comment: Where should we see about this changes? Changelog ?